# how to intercept "in" operator in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object, i want to intercept `in` opeartor access on the object.

e.g

```
myObject.operatorIn = ()=>throw new Error("You can't touch it :)")
```

Comment: Thankfully you cannot.

Answer (score 5):

With a Proxy, you can create a [`has` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/has) to intercept uses of `in`:

```js
const myObject = {
  foo: 'foo'
};
const myObjectProxy = new Proxy(
  myObject,
  {
    has() {
      throw new Error("You can't touch it");
    }
  }
);
console.log(myObjectProxy.foo);
console.log('foo' in myObjectProxy);
```